# How to create download popup (headers) for csv file with file_put_contents php

Tags: php, csv

I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers on how to create a download popup as well as a location for the user to save it.

So when they click on my "Download as CSV" button, it'll give the user a prompt to select a destination in their directory.

Currently, I'm able to get a file downloaded working, but it's only if I run it from my command line. I'm not too sure how to implement headers with this.

The main issue is because I can't use fopen(), fwrite(), and fclose() because I'm adding only a single (albeit BIG) string to the csv file.

Here's some code that works only if I run the program locally.

```
  $output = print_r(cleanUpEntry($info), true);
  file_put_contents("output.csv", $output);
```

It downloads the file to the same exact folder as my PHP file, but I need it to work on a webpage so that the user can download the file.

Note* I can't use fputcsv since it only works for arrays, and mine is a multidimensional array, so it's much easier to just get the output of print_r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send CSV file to the browser**

```php
$output = ...
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
echo $output;
exit;
```

Browsers tend to open files like CSVs, PDFs etc. To save the file instead of opening, add HTTP header `Content-Disposition`. For files larger few bytes, use `Content-Length` as well.

**Force browser to download file.**

```php
$output = ...
$filename = "output.csv";
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($output));
echo $output;
exit;
```

**Send static file to the browser**

Your web server (Apache, Nginx etc.) should handle static files, but in case you need to run it thru PHP for security or other reasons...

```php
$file = './files/myfile.csv';
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
readfile($file);
exit;
```

**Force browser to download a static file.**

```php
$file = './files/myfile.csv';
$filename = basename($file); // or specify directly, like 'output.csv'
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: For some reason, your "Force browser to download file." code gives me the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in line 63" (which is header(Content-Length: " . strlen($output);)

Comment: Ah, I've had a missing bracket typo. I've edited the answer, try now :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I did, but don't have enough reputation for it to show yet.. it will show up once I reach 15

Answer (score 0):

This uses old school `fopen`, `fputcsv`, and `fclose`, and not `file_put_contents` but always works for me...

```
    function csv_from_array($fileName, $data, $header_included = FALSE){
        // Downloads file - no return
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Pragma: public");
        $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        foreach($data as $line) {
            // Add a header row if not included
            if (!$header_included) {
                // Use the keys as titles
                fputcsv($fh, array_keys($line));
            }
            fputcsv($fh, $line);
        }
        fclose($fh);
        exit;
    }
```

Do you *need* to use `file_put_contents` for some reason?

If the file already exists / doesn't need to be created from a php array, you can modify as below:

```
    function download_csv($fileName){
        // Downloads file - no return
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Pragma: public");
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Like the note on the bottom says, I can't use fputcsv since that only works with arrays. In other words, foreach($data as $line) won't work. I have a multi-dimensional array that doesn't format nicely if I flatten it to a 1-D array, which is why I just get the output of print_r and save it using file_put_contents. Either way, the code that delta zero put down below works great!

Comment: Gotcha, that's why I added the second bit as well, once you have any file (print_r multidimensional saved to file) you can download it using that function. (same as delta zero's options) - either way, glad you got what you needed working!